# When rotating an image in Gimp 2.10.30 it rotates fine however the tools.are also rotating

Tags: gimp, image-editing

So I rotated my image about -15 degrees.  Now when I go to use the crop tool, it too assumes that I want that tool to be used at a rotation of -15 degres.  How can I tell Gimp to apply this rotation and use the tools as though nothing rotated?

Answer (score 2):

You [rotated the canvas](https://www.gimpusers.com/news/00475-gimp-canvas-rotation), not the image.

To rotate the image, go to either of

- tools -> transform tools -> rotate
- image -> transform -> arbitrary rotation

see also [this article](https://thegimptutorials.com/how-to-rotate-image/)